# Expected an array-like object, but found a Variable

Tags: theano

I am new to Theano. My question looks similiar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414306/theano-expected-an-array-like-object-but-found-a-variable-using-scan-categ) but it did not help me.
The problematic code is the following:

```
z0 = float32(random.randn(1, 1))
z = shared(z0)

x0 = float32(random.randn(N, 1))
x = shared(x0)

wo = shared(zeros((N, 1), dtype=float32))

z.set_value(T.dot(wo.T , x)) # here is the problem
```

This gives me the error: Expected an array-like object, but found a Variable.

I understand that z is a 1x1 numpy array and T.dot(wo.T , x) is a 1x1 vector but I did not succeed to find a way to assign the  1x1 vector to z.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use x.get_value() since x us a shared variable and the same for W as well.